# Embedding 2 Cases environments in one Align environment

Tags: align, cases

The problem has been solved:

I would like to embed two cases environments in one align environment. Here is the desired output:

[image: Desired Output]

Here is my MWE:

[image: Current Output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
% highlighting throughout the book
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font 
                      % together with math symbols from the Symbol, 
                      % Chancery and Computer Modern fonts
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{mathtools}       
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \delta &
    \begin{cases}
        \sigma  = \textrm{nanu nanu} & \iota = [0 - 0.5]\\
        \beta   = \textrm{nanu nanu} & \iota = (0.5 - 0.9)\\
        \tau    = \textrm{nanu nanu} & \iota = [0.9 - 1]
    \end{cases}
    \alpha &
    \begin{cases}
        \eta = \textrm{nanu nanu} \\
        \rho = \textrm{nanu nanu} \\
        \tau = \textrm{nanu nanu} \\
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, mutiple `cases` in one `align` are possible. The only problem in your code is that `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` are missing, there are empty lines in an align environment and you use more than one `&` in a cases environment. Fix this, than your cases work fine.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: thank you for the confirmation. On your first three points, these have been omitted intentionally to save space. I will try fooling around with the code to see if I can make better use of the `&` and fix the missing spaces.

Comment: Saving space may help you, but it doesn't help those trying to help you.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Point taken. Thank you.

Comment: @Marcel Krüger: I have solved the problem the advice given. Now I would like to add space between the two different cases. Do you have an idea on that?

Comment: @MichaelPerdue If you want to add horizontal space, you can always use `\hspace`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: Thank you. Problem solved. Do you think I should delete the question now?

Comment: Perhaps @MarcelKrüger can post an answer of his suggestions.

Comment: I think you can delete the question is not really answerable in current form as the example is unusable (two `\begin{document}` for example.) It could be fixed up but as your problem is solved, deleting is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
% highlighting throughout the book
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font 
                      % together with math symbols from the Symbol, 
                      % Chancery and Computer Modern fonts
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}       
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \delta
    \begin{cases}
        \sigma  = \textrm{nanu nanu} &  \iota=[0 - 0.5]\\
        \beta   = \textrm{nanu nanu} &  \iota=(0.5 - 0.9)\\
        \tau    = \textrm{nanu nanu} &  \iota=[0.9 - 1]
    \end{cases}
    & \qquad
    \alpha 
    \begin{cases}
        \eta = \textrm{nanu nanu} \\
        \rho = \textrm{nanu nanu} \\
        \tau = \textrm{nanu nanu} \\
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```